# BackboneJS calling a views render function from an event bound to a collection

Tags: events, backbone.js, collections, render, backbone-events

```
                    RoomsDGView = Backbone.View.extend({
                    collection: roomcollection,
                    initialize: function(){
                        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
                        this.$el.html( template );
                        this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded);
                        this.collection.bind('remove', this.modelremoved);
                        this.collection.bind('change', this.collectionchanged);
                        console.log(this);
                        this.render();
                    },
                    render: function(){
                        // Compile the template using underscore
                        console.log("running the render function...");
                        //renderrender();
                        /*$("#roomsList").jqGrid('clearGridData');
                        roomcollection.each(function (room,i){
                            var temp = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(room));
                            $("#roomsList").jqGrid('addRowData', i,{idrooms: temp["idrooms"], roomname: temp["roomname"],
                            occupants: temp["occupants"]});
                        });*/
                    },
                    events: {
                        "click input[type=button]": "doSearch"  
                    },
                    doSearch: function(){
                        // Button clicked
                        console.log(this);
                    },
                    modeladded: function() {
                        console.log("room added...");
                        $("#roomsList").jqGrid('clearGridData');
                        //My intent is to call the views render function
                        //her. I tried using this.render() and also 
                        //this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded(this));
                        //modeladded: function(view) {
                        //     view.render();
                        console.log(this);
                    },
                    modelremoved: function() {
                        console.log("room removed...");
                        $("#roomsList").jqGrid('clearGridData');
                    },
                    collectionchanged: function() {
                        console.log("room changed...");
                        $("#roomsList").jqGrid('clearGridData');
                    }
                });
```

I have tried many different ways to call the views render: method from inside the code for modeladded:. Use of this.render inside model added shows that the this object at that point has no render function. I also tried passing the view in something like:

this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded(this));

modeladded: function(view) {
    view.render();

which also leads to a console error that no render() can be found. Does anyone know how to call the views render: from inside modeladded?

For the time being I moved the render function out of the views render: and into a JavaScript function declared renderGlobal() declared in global scope and I know it does work that way but I don't think that is really the backbone.js way.

This is the error that is coming out of the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'render'

Thank you for posting....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding your event handler using [`bind` (AKA `on`)](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on):

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded);
```

But, as usual with JavaScript, the value of `this` inside a function depends on how the function is called, not how it is defined (ignoring bound functions of course). You're not specifying a specific `this` for your function anywhere so you're not getting any particular `this` when it is called. If you give `bind` the third context argument:

```
this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded, this);
// ------------------------------------------^^^^
```

then Backbone will call `modeladded` with the specific `this` and you'll find that `this` inside `modeladded` will be your view.

You could also use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to produce a bound version of your callback:

```
this.collection.bind('add', _(this.modeladded).bind(this));
this.collection.bind('add', this.modeladded.bind(this));
this.collection.bind('add', $.proxy(this.modeladded, this));
```

All of those produce new functions so you won't be able to [`unbind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-off) them without stashing the bound functions somewhere. You'll usually avoid using these when you have the option to specify the context (AKA `this`) explicitly.

There's also [`listenTo`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo):

> **listenTo** `object.listenTo(other, event, callback)`
>
> Tell an **object** to listen to a particular event on an **other** object. The advantage of using this form, instead of `other.on(event, callback, object)`, is that **listenTo** allows the **object** to keep track of the events, and they can be removed all at once later on. The **callback** will always be called with **object** as context.

So you can (and should) say this:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.modeladded);
```

That will take care of giving you the desired `this` and makes it easier to clean up your event handlers when you're done with them. Similarly for the other event handlers you're using.